# Netlogo: use forward command to move through list of patches

Tags: netlogo

I have a model where turtles create separate lists and then move along said list.  I am using the move-to command for the turtles to travel from one patch to the next. Here is the code calling the movement-

```
 face first current-path
 move-to first current-path
 set current-path remove-item 0 current-path
```

each turtle has a random speed variable however, while using the move-to command I am unable to have them move at different speeds. I imagine I need to use the forward command and have experimented with it extensively  but it either stops the simulation before the turtles have reached the end of the list or only runs once. Can i somehow use fd in combination with the jump command to ensure the turtles land directly on the patch in the list?

As I am relatively new to Netlogo and programming in general any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you look at Move Towards Target Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

Comment: That does help, however I am having more of an issue when figuring out how to iterate over the list. Using the towards and fd commands are pretty simple its using them with the lists that confuses me

Comment: How about editing your question to include your current code? Maybe we can help you with it.

Comment: I got it to work by ensuring the distance it moved in the fd command was small enough to allow the turtle to land on the exact xy cor; eliminating it from the list and moving on to the next patch. Although in my current solution the turtle is still moving to the first item in the list and then deleting it instead of going through each item in the list. Thanks a lot though